# Try with chained resource in JedisPool

Tags: java, jedis, try-with-resources

I am confused:
An usage: `try(Pipeline pipeline = jedisPool.getResource().pipelined())`
Will it close the pipeline and the jedis instance? Or just close the pipeline?

I use this with multi-threads, and I got the error as follow. I am confused that the error is caused by running out of instance in JedisPool(Due to the try-with-resource usage) or because a deadlock(For that JedisPool doesn't do well in multi-thread)?

```
sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2043)
org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.LinkedBlockingDeque.takeFirst(LinkedBlockingDeque.java:583)
org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:442)
org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:363)
redis.clients.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:49)
redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool.getResource(JedisPool.java:226)
io.codis.jodis.RoundRobinJedisPool.getResource(RoundRobinJedisPool.java:214)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try-with-resources close only variable, in your case `Pipeline pipeline`. You can read more in docs https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

You can check it with example:

`MyResource` class:

```
class MyResource implements AutoCloseable {

    public SubResource getSubResource() {
        return new SubResource();
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Resource closed");
    }
}
```

`SubResource` class:

```
class SubResource implements AutoCloseable{
    @Override
    public void close() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("SubResource closed");
    }
}
```

`Main` class:

```
class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (SubResource s = new MyResource().getSubResource()) {
            System.out.println("Before closing");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("After closing");
    }
}
```

Execution result:

```
Before closing
SubResource closed
After closing
```

Comment: wow~that's amazing!~ I have been wondering how to test the chained resource is closed, thx a lot!